# Split footline into three Warsaw Theme Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am using Warsaw theme and I want to modify the foot line. Now I have date and page number in my footline and I want to have date, "word I choose" and page number in my footline. It means that I want to split my footline into three and put "word I choose" in the middle of date and page number.

The following is the code that I have currently, which I want to modify.

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \vspace{1cm}% <- change here to whatever you want
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a custom footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%  
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}Word I choose
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\title{text}
\author{names}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

However as you already use a custom headline and frametitle and really not much of the Warsaw theme is left anyway, you could also switch to a theme which has a threepart footline by default:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \vspace{1cm}% <- change here to whatever you want
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}





\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatother


\title[Word I choose]{text}
\author[\today]{names}
\date[]{\today}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you don't care for nice alignment of the text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[threecols]{hackthefootline}
\title[word I choose]{text}
\author[\today]{names}
\date[]{\today}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]